# Grouping values into custom bins

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bins

I have a data frame with an 'education' attribute.  Values are discrete, 1-16.  For purposes of cross-tabulation, I want to bin this 'education' variable but with custom bins (1:8, 9:11, 12, 13:15, 16).

I've been fooling around with pd.cut() but I get an invalid syntax error

```
adult_df_educrace['education_bins'] = pd.cut(x=adult_df_educrace['education'], bins=[1:8, 9, 10:11, 12, 13:15, 16], labels = ['Middle School or less', 'Some High School', 'High School Grad', 'Some College', 'College Grad'])
```

Comment: bins must be a list of scalars corresponding to the bin edges, bins=[1,8, 9, 10,11, 12, 13, 15, 16]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the bins fall between the thresholds:

```
bins = [0.5, 8.5, 11.5, 12.5, 15.5, 16.5]
labels=['Middle School or less', 'Some High School', 
        'High School Grad', 'Some College', 'College Grad']

adult_df_educrace['education_bins'] = pd.cut(x=adult_df_educrace['education'],
                                             bins=bins,
                                             labels=labels)
```

Test:

```
adult_df_educrace = pd.DataFrame({'education':np.arange(1,17)})
```

Output:

```
    education         education_bins
0           1  Middle School or less
1           2  Middle School or less
2           3  Middle School or less
3           4  Middle School or less
4           5  Middle School or less
5           6  Middle School or less
6           7  Middle School or less
7           8  Middle School or less
8           9       Some High School
9          10       Some High School
10         11       Some High School
11         12       High School Grad
12         13           Some College
13         14           Some College
14         15           Some College
15         16           College Grad
```

Comment: Thanks for this code.  Unfortunately, this groups education=13 into "High School Grad" instead of "Some College."  I was looking to have only education=12 as "High School Grad"

Comment: I have 5 of each:

1-8:  "Middle School or Less"
9-11: "Some High School"
12:  "High School Grad"
13-15:  "Some College"
16:  "College Grad"

Comment: I came up with the same updated bins after playing around with it.  Looks like this works.  Thanks!